# Standardized symbol for "pay with bitcoin"

Tags: business

What symbol do I use to tell customers that our business accepts Bitcoin? For example many businesses use the visa symbol to show that they accept visa, But i want to know what is Bitcoin's equivalent? Should I use the "coin" symbol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although there is no official "Bitcoin Accepted Here" sign, the most popular graphics for this purpose seem to be these:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Source: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1631.0